# Put PHP data in HTML element

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I want to get my authenticated $userId as a value in an html element from the moment the function is executed (from the moment the user logs in) and place it in an input element in index.html

my AuthorizedAccessTokenController.php

```
class AuthorizedAccessTokenController
{
    public function getUser(Request $request)
    {
        //this is the key I want to place in my input
        $userId =  $request->user()->getKey();
        return $userId;
    }
}
```

this is the input in my index.html

```
<input type="text" value="the $userId">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get authenticated user's ID you can use `id()` method with `auth()` helper or `Auth` facade:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ auth()->id() }}">
```

Or:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ Auth::id() }}">
```

Comment: that method doesn't work so I need to do it differently. Not with Auth::id()

Comment: @hxwtch what do you mean by it doesn't work? Are you getting an error or something? Are you sure current user is authenticated? The primary key is ID in `users` table? Is this a plain Blade file or you're loading data with JS?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Note that you have to change your `index.html` to `index.php` if you want to execute PHP in it.

Comment: it gives the error: {error: "Unauthenticated."}. But the user is logged in. I even used  laravel Passport to log in a user and assigned it to a token but it still says that it's "Unauthenticated."

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<input type="text" value="' . $userid . '">';`

Put this inside the function where you get the User ID

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can prepend the `$` before the name of the function inside the string. This should do what you are looking for:

```
<input type="text" value="$getUser($REQUESTVARIABLE)">
```

It seems a method of a class so you have to call it properly with your object instance